# Breadcrumb with previous search result [RoR]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a search engine that needs to find a product in some address. When I click on this product, I want to have this breadcrumb:

State > City > Product

And this button:

[return to preview search]

If you click on the 'City', I want all the products from this city and so on. And the button [return to preview search] to get the exactly result from the page before.

I have some challenges here:

- *how do I get all this information stored with this specific URL ?*

I'm currently using in my project the combination of the gems **'pg_search'** and **'gretel'** + **'gretel-trails'** to make the search and to display the breadcrumbs, but I don't know how to store in the page this links.

One example is [this](https://www.trulia.com/property/3201606687-2101-1st-Ave-Altoona-PA-16602) page and they have:

> < Back to Search ( For Sale > PA > Altoona > 16602 > 2101 1st Ave )

Thank you.

Comment: Your breadrumb is wrong

Comment: Sorry, please tell me my mistake. Thanks.

Comment: see my answer below. Should help clear things up

Answer (score 0):

Your breadcrumb is wrong which is why you are struggling
Instead of

> State > City > Product

It should read

> West Yorkshire > Leeds > Red blanket

That way with the use of cookies (Session object) and storing the state value and the City value at each stage you can then just do a search based on the current values for those fields in the products table

Something like

```
@products = Product.where("county = ? AND city = ?", session.current_county, session.current_city)
```

Obviously adjust the above depending on whether or not the values exist in the session and make sure you set and clear the session values in the right places to ensure no city is in the session when you have just chosen the state to enable you to adjust the where condition depending on the existence of the session variables.

Also note that state is a reserved word so should be avoided hence the use of county instead of state

If you really don't want to use session then make use of the request object

```
request.original_url
```

**UPDATE**

This code in your application layout or whatever layout your public views descend from will set the bread crumb based on the URL

```
    def set_breadcrumb(path)
        @breadcrumbs = []
#       unless path.downcase.begins_with? "session" do
        begin
            build_path = []
            build_title = ''
            r = Rails.application.routes
            @breadcrumbs << [{text: "Home", url: '/'}] #TODO Cater for spanish translation
            #{text: text, url: url[0]}
            path.each_with_index do |crumb, i|
                if crumb.downcase.to_s != "home"
                    #if crumb.to_s.downcase != "countries"
                    build_path << crumb
                    #end
                    #build_title = build_title + crumb + " "
        #           [{:text=>"Chile", :url=>"/chile-travel"}, {:text=>"Facts", :url=>"/chile-facts"}]
                    text = crumb.humanize.titleize
    #               r.generate controller: 'peru/facts'
                    p = build_path.join('/')
                    #logger.debug("@@@@ path #{url_for controller: p}")
                    #url = r.generate controller: p action: 'index'
                    url =  r.generate controller: p unless p.downcase == "countries"
                    #logger.debug("@@@@ path generated #{url}")
                    #logger.debug("@@@@ path generated 2 #{url_for(url)}")
                    @breadcrumbs << [{text: text, url: url[0]}] unless url.blank?
                end
            end
        rescue  ActionController::UrlGenerationError => e

        end
    end
```

Then call the method in a before filter

```
before_action :set_title_and_breadcrumb
```

And use it in a partial template like this

```
<%if top_breadcrumb_style%>
    <%chevron = ' >'%>
<%else%>
    <%chevron = ''%>
<%end%>
<p>
    You are here <%=chevron%>
</p>
<%@breadcrumbs.each_with_index do |crumb, i|%>
    <% if i < @breadcrumbs.size - 1 %>
        <%= link_to "#{crumb[0][:text]} #{chevron}", crumb[0][:url]%>
    <%else%>

        <p>
            <%= crumb[0][:text].humanize %>
        </p>
    <% end %>
<%end%>
```

Pop that in a partial and render it wherever you need it

Now you have two options to grab the city and the state for use with your where clause. You can interrogate the bread crumb or the URI path for the values you need to include.
Hope that helps

Comment: Ji jamesc, thank you and I sorry because I don't want to have this page depending on the cookies because everyone couldn't have the same page with the same links on the breadcrumb when get into this link.

Comment: @FillypeFarias Session object cookie is the correct solution and there are no flaws in using sessions to store state for a user. Not sure why you would be worried about this unless you don't understand cookies in which case you should read up on using Rails session object here https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-rails-sessions-work/

Comment: I'll check it out more carefully but how can I have this: I share with you a link page and both of us have the same breadcrumb ?

Comment: @FillypeFarias I've updated my answer, It makes no difference if both have same breadcrumb! We have different sessions. Use request object if you prefer as per my update

Comment: Sorry sorry, the problem is that I want the same breadcrumb A > B > C > D with the same URL associated with these links "http://X" > "http://Y" > "http://Z" > "http://W" for EVERYONE that goes to the link http://www.mywebsite.com/2343432product#this_result and it should not depend on the cookie stored, but the url link itself objectively.

Comment: @FillypeFarias perhaps this will help http://smsohan.com/blog/2009/07/07/implementing-breadcrumb-in-rails/

Comment: @FillypeFarias See my updated answer, it might help point you in the right direction. It builds the breadcrumb from the path and also sets the page title, It is a solution I have used in the past and can be i18n'd